# Unsupported Gauge Version: This veuge Inrsion of Gatellij plugin only works with Gauge version >= 0.9.0, spec files steps are shown unimplemented

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, getgauge

//unexpected gauge plugin error comes

I'm completely new to gauge and asked to create a sample gauge project as POC, followed the official documentation but got the error and couldn't come across and i'm stuck here

Steps followed:

1. JDK 1.8 was already configured in my system with environment/system variables configured properly
2. Installed jetbrains intellij-IDEA of version 2019.
3. Installed gauge on the machine and configured the system variable
4. Then created a maven project and added a archetype as suggested in blog 
   com.thoughtworks.gauge.maven:gauge-maven-plugin
   GroupId: “com.thoughtworks.gauge.maven:
   ArtifactId: “gauge-archetype-java” and selected the template.
5. got the couple gauge dependencies(gauge java, gauge plugin) in my pom.xml file.
6. verified the project structure, all required directories were listed.
7. But when opened the spec file or as soon as i open my IDE i get this error saying unsupported gauge plugin error, it must be >=0.9.0.

need some help here to get rid of that, because of which though the step implementation was mapped and developed still the steps in .spec file have error saying they are unimplemented.Thanks in advance

1. I was going through a bug that said exactly the same error in git hub and checked my binary path for gauge, there i've manually chnaged to 0.9.0 from 0.3.15.
2. path is set to "C:/program Files/gauge/bin, i've tried chnanging this with the path where i had my gauge plugin libraries
   Eg: C:\Users\pradeep\Downloads\Gauge-Java-Intellij-0.3.15\Gauge-Java-Intellij\lib

raising a new question as i'm not currently clarified with what to change as my binary path or anyother to fix

https://github.com/kpkk/Gauge-POC - code is available here, on my git repositories

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're referring an outdated blog and setup instructions. The sample POC you shared works fine on the latest version of gauge v1.0.5 and [IntelliJ-plugin v0.3.15](https://github.com/getgauge/Intellij-Plugin#installation). Please try following the [instructions](https://docs.gauge.org/latest/installation.html) to install Gauge.

After installing gauge create a sample maven project by running the following command on the windows command prompt.

```
gauge init java_maven
```

You can open this newly created project in IntelliJ