# Unsupported Gauge Version: This version of Gauge Intellij plugin only works with Gauge version >= 0.9.0

Tags: java, linux, maven, intellij-idea, gauge

I've a gauge project that I've been using since January 2019 and out of nowhere I started getting this unsupported gauge version error. I thought it was due to an update, either in gauge, intellij or the gauge intellij plugin but this seems not to be the case.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling gauge, the gauge plugin, intellij, creating a new sample project on my machine and manually specifying the gauge binary path and home. None of these have made any difference. The new sample project has the same issue. However, other machines running the same project seem to have no issue, even on the same version of gauge and intellij. That said, I'm not sure if this would make a difference but I'm running on an Ubuntu machine (18.04) while they were running Windows 10. I've followed the documentation for installing gauge as specified in the following question: [Unsupported Gauge Version: This veuge Inrsion of Gatellij plugin only works with Gauge version >= 0.9.0, spec files steps are shown unimplemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847354/unsupported-gauge-version-this-veuge-inrsion-of-gatellij-plugin-only-works-with)

I can still run specs, but some of the functionality of the plugin is no longer available. In particular, where before when running each scenario in a spec was separated into it's own header which had it's own log, now all the scenarios are grouped into one log, often times causing most of the scenario logs to be lost due to the amount of lines in the log.

Edit: I'm running with the following gauge version:
Gauge version: 1.0.6,
Commit Hash: 2bc49db,
html-report (4.0.8),
java (0.7.2),
screenshot (0.0.1)
As for intellij:
Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2019.2
Gauge plugin 0.3.16

Comment: You seem to have missed one crucial piece of information: what version of Gauge and the plugin are you actually using?

Comment: Sorry I'll fix that

Comment: You may want to report a bug at https://github.com/getgauge/Intellij-Plugin/issues.

Comment: Done that now: https://github.com/getgauge/Intellij-Plugin/issues/392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I've specified gauge binary path in idea's settings->search for gauge, but it didn't helped straight away.

Issue was fixed it with turning off the telemetry:

`gauge telemetry off`

Worked on linux mint 19.1, with idea 2019.2, plugin 0.3.6, gauge 1.0.6